# Is frame.revalidate() important to get output after an event?

Tags: java, swing, layout, event-handling

So, I've wrote a code where you get a rectangle after you click the button on the south region of the frame.

But the code didn't seem to work after the button is clicked because of this

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev){
    Drawing d = new Drawing();
    frame.add(d);
    frame.repaint();
   }
```

and the I add `revalidate()` inside the block.

```
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev){
    Drawing d = new Drawing();
    frame.add(d);
    frame.revalidate();
    frame.repaint();
   }
```

now the code works just fine, but from where I've been studying they didn't use `revalidate()` and their code worked.

why is this happening?

Comment: `revalidate` calls `invalidate` and `validate` on the container.  This causes the container to undergo a layout pass, updating all the components sizes and locations based on the layout requirements.  Swing is lazy, that is, it won't update the layout until you (or something else) triggers it, so, yes, it's important.  Why does the code your studying work, no idea, we have no reference to it

Comment: I am currently studying head first java 2nd edition  [link](https://zimslifeintcs.files.wordpress.com/2011/12/head-first-java-2nd-edition.pdf) page 371. The code is a bit different but they did not use `revalidate()`

Comment: So, the example you've linked to is using custom painting, see [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) and [Painting in Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for more details.  All this is does is changes what the component paints, it does not affect the size or position of the component (or the other components in the container), so you don't need `revalidate`

Comment: Now I get it, if you are adding any component to the frame, you need to update the frame manually by calling `revalidate()`. Otherwise, for existing components in the frame, we dont need to do it.

Comment: So long as the change (to existing components) don’t affect the size of the component. Changing the text of a JLabel could affect its size, but the good news there, is JLabel#setText can trigger a update it self

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the example you've cited is using a custom painting approach to paint the component. This does not (directly) affect the size or location of the component, so it doesn't need the container to perform a new layout pass.

See [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) and [Painting in Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for more details

Your code is adding a new component to the container, so you need to tell the container when you want the container to be laid out again.

So, from the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#revalidate--)

> public void revalidate()
>  Supports deferred automatic layout. Calls
>   invalidate and then adds this component's validateRoot to a list of
>   components that need to be validated. Validation will occur after all
>   currently pending events have been dispatched. In other words after
>   this method is called, the first validateRoot (if any) found when
>   walking up the containment hierarchy of this component will be
>   validated. By default, JRootPane, JScrollPane, and JTextField return
>   true from isValidateRoot.
>
> This method will automatically be called on this component when a
>   property value changes such that size, location, or internal layout of
>   this component has been affected. This automatic updating differs from
>   the AWT because programs generally no longer need to invoke validate
>   to get the contents of the GUI to update.